# How can disable wordpress emails notifications?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to modularly disable emails sent out by WordPress so I can replace them with my own custom emails when necessary.

This is my custom Welcome Email:

```
  function send_welcome_email_to_new_user($user_id) {
    $user = get_userdata($user_id);
    $user_email = $user->user_email;
    // for simplicity, lets assume that user has typed their first and last name when they sign up
    $user_full_name = $user->user_firstname . $user->user_lastname;

    // Now we are ready to build our welcome email
    $to = $user_email;
    $subject = "Hi " . $user_full_name . ", welcome to our site!";
    $body = '
              <h1>Dear ' . $user_full_name . ',</h1></br>
              <p>Thank you for joining our site. Your account is now active.</p>
              <p>Please go ahead and navigate around your account.</p>
              <p>Let me know if you have further questions, I am here to help.</p>
              <p>Enjoy the rest of your day!</p>
              <p>Kind Regards,</p>
              <p>poanchen&lt;/p>
    ';
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    if (wp_mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
      error_log("email has been successfully sent to user whose email is " . $user_email);
    }else{
      error_log("email failed to sent to user whose email is " . $user_email);
    }
  }
```

When I create a new user, I got 2 email notification: my own custom email and wordpress default email. I want to hide the wordpress default email from the inbox.

How can I disable WordPress emails notifications to achieve this?

- Thank you for signing up/New User registration email

Answer (score 1):

To disable WordPress default emails notifications

Please edit the function.php file and add the following code

```
<?php
//Disable the new user notification sent to the site admin
function wp_disable_new_user_notifications() {
//Remove original use created emails
remove_action( ‘register_new_user’, ‘wp_send_new_user_notifications’ );
remove_action( ‘edit_user_created_user’, ‘wp_send_new_user_notifications’, 10, 2 );

}
```

then

```
add_action( ‘init’, ‘wp_disable_new_user_notifications’ );
```

However, please be **careful** in using the above so that the remove_action will not affect any other functionalities you may wish to use in WP

Comment: Don't you think removing actions is not a good practice? There are many other functionalities depending on the WordPress actions. You may find an email notification specific action.

Comment: Alright. I just concerned, might be other functions are attached to these particular actions which may stop working after removing the same

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating an another email for the same, you can also customize WordPress default emails using `wp_new_user_notification()` function.

```
add_filter( 'wp_new_user_notification_email', 'custom_wp_new_user_notification_email', 10, 3 );
function custom_wp_new_user_notification_email( 
  $wp_new_user_notification_email, $user, $blogname ) {
  $user_first_name = stripslashes( $user->first_name );
  $user_last_name = stripslashes( $user->last_name );
  $user_full_name = $user_first_name .' '.  $user_last_name;
  $user_email = stripslashes( $user->user_email );
  $wp_new_user_notification_email['subject'] = "Hi " . $user_full_name . ", welcome to our site!";
  
  $message = '
          <h1>Dear ' . $user_full_name . ',</h1></br>
          <p>Thank you for joining our site. Your account is now active. 
          </p>
          <p>Please go ahead and navigate around your account.</p>
          <p>Let me know if you have further questions, I am here to help. 
          </p>
          <p>Enjoy the rest of your day!</p>
          <p>Kind Regards,</p>
          <p>poanchen&lt;/p>
  ';
  return $wp_new_user_notification_email;
}
```

Learn more about `wp_new_user_notification()` [Here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_new_user_notification/)